# Why OptaPlanner example runs very slow on WildFly but fast on Oracle JVM?

Tags: wildfly, scheduling, optaplanner

I modify the OptaPlanner 6.5 course timetabling example to a REST service using the vehiclerouting web example as a template. We found that the web version of course timetabling run very slow as compared to pure Java version of course timetabling.

For example, the pure Java edition timetabling system can get a 0Hard/-352Soft score. But the web edition can only get -7Hard/-1108Soft. No matter how long we run the example.

The web edition is hosted in a WildFly 9. The JVM versions we use are both Oracle JVM 1.8; Further, we tried using WildFly 10. And the result is the same.

Can anyone shed some light on it? I want get the same performance in web edition as Java edition.

Comment: Did you verify the data in the scheduling itself is actually the same? Perhaps after implementing the REST service something is wrong (duplicate items, ids, ...), leading to a different planning problem. You could try and save (plain text, xml, json) the initial solution with the planning entities/variable-list and compare this for both versions

Comment: I finally found the source of this issue:  I used setScoreFileList to use a dynamic generated drl file. If I remove this line of code and the engine can get 0Hard score in one second. But if I put it on, then the result is not feasible. Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Thanks Chris,  I am sure the data set is correct. As I drill down, I have found the root cause of this issue: SetScoreFileList. If i call it to set a dynamic generated drl file, the solution will not be feasible no matter how long i solve. What's wrong with the API? My code is like this:   File file = new File(drl);  List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>(1); sessionSolverFactory.getSolverConfig().getScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().setScoreDrlFileList(fileList);