# Why optaplanner can not find feasible solution when I use setScoreDrlFileList api

Tags: rest, optaplanner

If i call setScoreDrlFileList to set a dynamic generated drl file, the solution will not be feasible no matter how long i solve. What's wrong with the API? My code is like this:

```
File file = new File(drl); 
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>(1); 
sessionSolverFactory.getSolverConfig().getScoreDirectorFacto‌​ryConfig().setScoreD‌​rlFileList(fileList)‌​;
```

if I remove setScoreD‌​rlFileList and use classpath resource : "org/optaplanner/examples/curriculumcourse/solver/curriculumCourseScoreRules.drl" my app can find a feasible solution in a second! What's wrong?

My application is a cloning of curriculum web example. The optaplanner version is 6.5 and JVM is oracle 1.8

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure there is a feasible solution? See "overconstrained planning" in docs.

Comment: Is this still the setup from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484259/why-optaplanner-example-runs-very-slow-on-wildfly-but-fast-on-oracle-jvm ?

Comment: Yes. I am sure there is a feasible solution. Because I can get the feasible solution using the Java version of the timetabling system. I currently solve this problem this way: put the drlFile in the classpath, then setScoreDrlList(Arrays.asList(drlFile)); After that, the timetabling system can get a feasible solution in one second! Thanks Chris!